# In Oracle Stored Procedure I am passing parameter as String to check the IN condition. This is not yielding results

Tags: oracle11g

pInCon I am passing as ('1','2')

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE proc1
(
 pInCon in Varchar2,     
 P_RECORDSET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR  
) AS 
BEGIN
        open    P_RECORDSET for

    SELECT col1,col2
    FROM table1
    WHERE col1 IN pInCon;        
END  proc1;
```

But when I do a select, I am seeing values. Pls help

Comment: select regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
  connect by regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your intention is to pass in multiple values rather than a single string that contains single quotes, commas, etc. the best option would be to pass in an actual collection.  Something like

```
CREATE TYPE num_table
   AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1( p_in IN num_table,
                                   p_recordset OUT sys_refcursor )
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_recordset 
   FOR SELECT col1, col2
         FROM table1
        WHERE col1 IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE( p_in ));
END;
```

If you really need to pass in a string of comma-separated values rather than a collection, you could parse the string that is passed in into a collection in your stored procedure.  Tom Kyte has the canonical post on [handling variable IN lists](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061) that walks through that approach.

It is also possible to use dynamic SQL.  That has numerous downsides, though.  It is slower, it likely makes other things running in this database slower by flooding the shared pool with non-sharable statements, it introduces the potential for SQL injection attacks, etc.